# Xcode 5 static analyzer hangs

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, clang-static-analyzer

Project (iOS 7) has 220 files, analysis currently hangs at file #154.

Pressing the "Stop" (square) button has no effect, attempting to quit Xcode causes the "Do you want to stop tasks?" prompt, but Xcode still doesn't quit even if you choose "Stop Tasks". On Apple Menu -> Force Quit..., Xcode appears as "responsive" (non-red characters). Force-quitting from there will allow relaunch. But it will all start again the next time I start the analyzer.

Anyone having the same issue?

**EDIT:** After using Activity Monitor, I found out its the `clang` process (100% CPU, 16.8 MB RAM) that hangs (even after Xcode is killed). I filed a bug at Apple with number: `15094688`.

**EDIT 2:** I filed a radar and got feedback that the issue was fixed in a later Xcode release.

Comment: Certainly see plenty of Xcode hangs, but not this specific one -- usually while debugging.